# I need help finding an easier way of going through an exponentially growing list to find the total count of lanternfish for advent of code

Tags: c#

So I'm currently working on a advent of code answer display. This code is a bit chunky. I want to know if anyone by chance knew a simpler way of writing the code? 
(Day 6 - year 2021 - Adventofcode)

The data is the following: 3,4,3,1,2 
And the following is the expected answer: 26984457539

```
public static List<string> Star()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new("./Data/2021/Day06.txt");
        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        List<int> allLanternCycle = Array.ConvertAll(data.Split(","), int.Parse).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < allLanternCycle.Count; j++)
            {
                if (allLanternCycle[j] == 0)
                {
                    allLanternCycle[j] = 7;
                    allLanternCycle.Add(9);
                }
                allLanternCycle[j]--;
            }
        }



        return new List<string>() { "", "true" };
    }
```

Comment: Hint: You only need 8 or 9 distinct counters to keep track of the whole thing

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of a List<>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each lanternfish only has 9 possible states, 1 of which "resets" immediately, so you only need to keep track of *how many* lanternfish are in each of the remaining 8 states at any given time.

That means you only need an array of 8 counters to solve the problem of keeping a count of them all:

```
var fishPerState = new long[8];
foreach(int state in Array.ConvertAll(data.Split(","), int.Parse))
{
    fishPerState[state - 1]++;
}
```

Now that we have a tracking mechanism, we need a way to advance the program. Every day, each fish changes to a state lower (eg. 8 -> 7), except for fish in state 1, which will "reset and repopulate":

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    // move all fish in states 2-8 to one state lower
    var temp = new long[8];
    Array.Copy(fishPerState, 1, temp, 0, 7);

    // reproduce
    temp[7] = fishPerState[0];

    // reset
    temp[5] += fishPerState[0];

    // assign new state counts to array variable
    fishPerState = temp;
}
```

Now you don't need to worry about memory constraints, as you only ever use 128 bytes (8 longs * 8 bytes * 2 arrays) of memory regardless of how many lanternfish you count.

If the target count exceeds the capacity of a `long` (2^63-1), use the `BigInteger` type for the array elements instead :)

Comment: Nice! It almost worked right away, just needed to edit the length of the arrays, since this one reproduces 1 cycle too fast! Thanks for the awsome explaination & answer!